# What services/applications require correct reverse DNS (PTR) records?

Tags: dns

I have just had to contact BT to add reverse DNS records for my mail server, in the hope that my emails might stop going into the Junk folder of one particular email provider ... Not naming any names ... *cough* Out *cough* Look ...

(Note: I am aware that this may not be the end of the issue with them)

But, It got me thinking, and wondered if there are any other applications that use the reverse DNS for some sort of authentication ... One I was thinking about was applying for Enterprise level SSL Certificates. Has anyone had an issue with this? Or any other services/applications?

Answer (score 0):

Any and *every* service which logs connections will be enhanced significantly (for the service operator) by accurate rDNS!

Missing or broken or bogus rDNS is a major hindrance for anyone and *everyone* trying to debug network connectivity issues with the endpoint in question.